# How to append html to the last paragraph of a class in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a page with several .desc divs. I want to add some html to the last paragrahs within these divs.

I have tried this..

```
$(".desc p:last").append(" <span class='orange readMore'>Read More</span> <span class='orange readLess'>Read Less</span>");
```

However this just adds it to the last paragraph of that div in the whole page. Not to each last paragrapgh within .desc div. If this makes sense...

```
<div class="desc">

                <p>Description1</p> 
            </div>
<div class="desc">
                <p>Description2 <span class="orange readMore" style="display: inline; ">Read More</span> <span class="orange readLess" style="display: none; ">Read Less</span></p> 
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".desc").each(function(){
    $(this).find('p:last').append("<span class='orange readMore'>Read More</span> <span class='orange readLess'>Read Less</span>");
});
```

Something like this maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`:last-child`](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) instead:

```
$(".desc p:last-child").append("Some stuff");
```

The `:last` selector will always reduce the matched set to the last element in that set. It will only ever return one element.

From the docs for `:last-child` (the following quote perfectly describes your exact problem):

> While `:last` matches only a single element, `:last-child` can match more
>   than one: one for each parent.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

$("div.desc').each(function () {
   $(this).find('p:last').after(" Read More Read Less");
});